# Is being sent on consultation a warning sign of a bad skill?

Tags: consulting

I worked at a software house which led internal projects and also sent consultants to other companies.

I started working there about 6 months ago, during this time I have been trained on some framework I have never used, and today they told me that between 2-3 weeks I should have been assigned to external projects with some clients of theirs.

I'm not totally sure if this is bad or good recognition of my skill, because I have been trained on the same framework used in my company.

Am I so good that it is better to send me outside to show my company in a good light or am I not as good as the people INSIDE the company?

EDIT: I don't know why I'm getting so many close votes, my question is relevant on the site scope, is general to be useful to other users and I'm not asking for a personal opinion

Comment: It means they need someone for external projects. No more, no less. Don't overthink this.

Comment: We can't answer this, because we don't know if your companies sends out their best people to impress their clients or their worst people to be rid of them.

Comment: You're an ambassador for your company. It's fantastically unlikely that they'd send you off if they thought there was any chance that you might cast them in a bad light.

Answer (score 7):

This is a good sign, it means they think you are competent and professional enough to represent the company to clients. So it's more than just about your technical skills.

Do the best you can and remain professional at all times, you will be under scrutiny and this can be a big boost for your career.

Comment: +1, Exactly, I don't know of a single company that is willing to show their bad employees to their customers/clients/partners. If they are testing you, they would most likely have sent someone to go with you to see how things went.

Answer (score 1):

This can be seen through several factors.

- They want to test your skills
- You're good enough to represent the company at a client
- The client need more man-power at his/her company and don't mind having someone to learn the environment.

This all depends on how your boss see you and your skills. This can be either good or bad. But I don't think "bosses" will send out people to represent the company if the didn't believe that the employed had the correct skills or the brains to learn them. So I would see this as a positive thing, and a good way for you to prove your worth to the company.

Good luck!